# debug iphone app data source

Tags: iphone, debugging, datasource

I'd like to debug/monitor what my iphoneapp retrieves from my website from the iphone.
i.e. My iphone app retrieves some prices for products from my website http://mywebsite.com:xxxx/getPrice/items

How do I see it from the iPhone itself that it is doing what it is suppose to do?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

If the data retrieve is textual and you're using the debugger, you can use NSLog to dump the raw data retrieved to the console (after converting from NSData to NSString, which is easy). Otherwise, just have an UILabel or something output stuff to the screen.

Comment: i'd prefer not to modify the code if possible. Any way we debug?

Comment: This solution requires about two lines of code.  That's going to be far easier than network sniffing or some other method.